# Disabling ONLY no_zero_date in MySQL 5.7.24

Tags: mysql

I need zero dates for my applications so I'm facing the strict MySQL mode constraint. 
As suggested by many, I've disabled the strict mode by creating a disable_mysql_strict_mode.cnf file:

`[mysqld] 
sql_mode="IGNORE_SPACE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"`

Now I can set dates to zero but it turns out that ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is also disabled which I don't want. 
It looks like it's all or nothing.
Is there any way to be specific when disabling strict mode ?

Comment: If you are loading more than one *.cnf file, make sure that the server is actually reading them all and double-check you aren't setting `sql_mode` twice. It's also worth testing everything in session (`SET sql_mode = '...'`) to ensure it works.

Comment: zero dates? Why not use NULL values instead? And use SELECT CASE WHEN date IS NULL THEN ‘0000:00:00’ ELSE date END AS date

Comment: The applications I work with rely on zero dates, using NULL would implies to modify many code lines.

Comment: It isn't intuitively sensible that setting `@@sql_mode` to a value that **includes** `NO_ZERO_DATE` would make it work... so you are sort of stumbling into a solution that works because it doesn't actually include a strict mode (which `NO_ZERO_DATE` depends on).  What isn't clear to me is why the solution isn't simply to add `,ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` to the end of that sql_mode string.  Isn't that all you need?

Comment: You're right, but some values in the sql_mode variable are misleading. 
If I add `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` to the end of the sql_mode string as you suggest, it works and I have a error if my query refers to nonaggregated columns.
Now why there is no error when I set a date to zero whereas `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE` and `NO_ZERO_DATE` are mentionned in the sql_mode string ?

Comment: @Duddy67 strict mode causes MySQL to treat most warnings as errors and abort the query. It's possible that `NO_ZERO_DATE` only produces warnings, and since you've disabled strict mode these aren't getting converted into errors